# Событие oninput срабатывает только при нажатии пробела

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть сайт украшений. На странице оформления заказа есть инпут для ввода названия города доставки. К нему прикручен скрипт, который по событию oninput подтягивает список городов  из базы КЛАДР. Прикол в том, что с компа с любого браузера все работает без проблем, только вводишь букву и появляются варианты городов. Но когда заходишь с телефона, результаты поиска начинают подгружаться только если после ввода букв нажимаешь пробел.

Пишу на Vue

```js
fetchKLADR() {
      this.kladrShow = true;
      if(this.myPlaceholder == 'ГОРОД') {
        this.$store.dispatch('PostRequest', {
          url: 'https://rushev.online/server/kladr_city.php',
          body: this.getInfo
        });
      }
      if(this.myPlaceholder == 'ОБЛАСТЬ') {
        this.$store.dispatch('PostRequest', {
          url: 'https://rushev.online/server/kladr_region.php',
          body: this.getInfo
        });
      }
    }
```

```html
<input v-bind:type="myType" required v-bind:placeholder="myPlaceholder" v-model="getInfo" :class="{empty:empty}"
           @blur="save" @input.prevent="fetchKLADR">
```

Comment: Код покажите)))

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.